# Based on RESTful query results, Launch a specific activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a Cloud Endpoints generated library in Android Studio. The Endpoints library interacts with a Cloud SQL database that I have.

In my Android application I have a MainActivity with a button. Clicking this button takes you to ActivityA.

However, I have a table in my Cloud SQL database that I want to query upon clicking this button. If that table has a certain entry, I want to launch ActivityB instead.

So by default clicking the button launches ActivityA, but if something exists in the database, I want to launch ActivityB.

How should I set it up so that when you click my button, the Endpoints API (which is a REST API) queries the database, and based on the query results either launch ActivityA or ActivityB?

The reason I ask is because I know you are supposed to put Restful calls into an AsyncTask to prevent the UI from getting hung up. However, AsyncTasks run in the background, so by the time it processes the query, it may be too late and ActivityA will just launch anyways.

Comment: Why you cant just lunch Activity you need on Asyncatask complete?

Comment: or do the query in MainActivity, before user click the button.

Comment: 1. activ=Main  onButton do ... 2. Async Get DB 3. on Async finish parse dataB data and change state, change model  4. Based on chgs to #3 launch either Activ A or Activ B  from Main .... not Main to A to B   get the data on the button event

Comment: @JiangYD Good idea. But there may be another situation where the database entry may change right in between the MainActivity being loaded and the user clicking the button.

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thank you for commenting and I very much appreciate your comment but I am a little confused from it. Maybe if you have time could you fashion an answer from it? Sorry - noob here...

Comment: @AntonA. Is the the normal way to do things in Android? I thought that if you do that, the UI might hang for a second before moving to the next activity. Just trying to see what is best practices here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to start new activity based on the result of the Google Cloud Endpoint ApiMethod response you can use [onPostExecute(Result)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) like [HelloEndpoints](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints) example wait to show Toast. In that example android client wait for String value of the MyBean response of sayHi apiMethod.

But according to your this comment.

> But there may be another situation where the database entry may change right in between the MainActivity being loaded and the user clicking the button.

I think what you try to achieve can't be done by using a REST service due to time duration that is spent on sending response back to your android client. Lets say Endpoint send response to your client and your client get it after 1 second. During  that one second time period database values can be changed.

Comment: One thing I tried was showing a ProgressDialog in onPreExecute in the AsyncTask when the user clicks the button. Then, when the data is ready, I launch the appropriate activity. Can't think of a better way to do it =(